# Shouldn't the primary page show meta participation?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, election

Gaming is currently in [the primary phase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=primary) of its elections, and I noticed that the primary page does not show the candidates' participation on the meta site.

> [image: screenshot]

[The nomination page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=nomination) shows that information.

> [image: screenshot]

Is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have been an issue with caching - I'll watch the next election to make sure.